# Запись выбранного города в localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер! Сразу скажу, что не силен в js - jquery. Задача следующая, есть всплывающее окно, в котором выводятся списки городов и стран. По выбору страны, города подгружаются на ajax, потом человек выбирает город и переходит на страницу этого города.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сохранить в localstorage название города и потом выводить его в шапке сайта, то есть просто строку с текстом, которую необходимо взять со ссылки города по которой нажимаем для перехода на его страницу.

На данном этапе наваял такой код:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
 var val_input=$(this).text();
 localStorage.setItem('keycity',val_input);
});

if(localStorage.getItem('keycity')){
 $('#loccity').html(localStorage.getItem('keycity'));
 }
  
</script>
```

Comment: Молодец! В чем проблема? Или Вы просто хотели поделиться?

Comment: Не работает почему-то. По синтаксису правильно?

Comment: Что такое `'.dropdown-toggle'`?

Comment: Это класс ссылки, их много на странице с таким классом

Comment: Второй фрагмент в других страницах тоже есть? Клик обрабатывается? Добавьте туда `console.log(val_input);`.

Comment: Может, всё обернуть в `$( document ).ready( ... )`? Иначе установка значения может не выполниться.

Comment: В общем поэкспериментировал немного, получается что эти строки не работают для тех элементов, которые появляются при подгрузке подкатегорий посредством ajax. И тут сложность..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делегирование:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){
    var val_input=$(this).text();
    localStorage.setItem('keycity',val_input);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, дальше справлюсь